# Can anyone help identify this piece of equipment?

Tags: transformer, identification, vintage

My father—in-law was an electrical engineer and had a great collection of audio and electronic equipment. I’m not sure what this is. Can anyone help?

It has a cable with 3 connectors on one end that would fit in the 3 ports on the front. The other end of the cable has red and black clamps that look like little jumper cables. There is a switch on the top like the one in front, but without a label. It fits into a nice wooden box.

[image]

Comment: The front panel is too generic to suggest a purpose. A photograph of the interior wiring would be much more informative. Is there a transformer inside?

Comment: A picture of what's inside would help with an ID.

Comment: Is that a second toggle lever on the far/back side? What's the circle segment showing there?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I’m out of town this week but I’ll open it up when I get a chance and take some more pics and get your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a DIY phase sequence detector, along the lines of [this sort of thin](http://time-mark.com/shop/3-phase-testers/208a-208240v/)g:

[image]

Such a device is used to verify or determine the phase sequence of 3-phase power so that motors are not inadvertently run in reverse (which can damage some types of equipment).